# ANT+ FE-C Writing User Configuration data Page 55 (0x37) to Smart Trainer - no change in resistance noticed

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am trying to write user configuration data (Data Page 55, 0x37) to a smart fitness device (bicycle trainer) via FE-C over Bluetooth. Although using different values or using the max values I do not notice any change in resistance. Is there a mistake processing the data? The second method (private static byte[] CreateFECUserConfiguration()) returns a byte array which will be written to the device.

```
private async Task WriteUserConfiguration(GattCharacteristic characteristic)
{
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter();
    
    byte[] bytes = CreateFECUserConfiguration();
    
    writer.WriteBytes(bytes);
    
    var valResult = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());
    if (valResult == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Write UserConfiguration Successful");
    }
}
    

// create values for testing, will be provided by the user later on
private static byte[] CreateFECUserConfiguration()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[13]; // size of message
    UInt16 userWeight = (ushort)(655.34 / 0.01); // 0-655.34
    byte[] userWeightBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(userWeight);
    
    byte bicycleWheelDiameterOffset = 10; // 0-10, 0.5 byte
    UInt16 bicycleWeight = 50 * 20; // 0 – 50, * 20, 1.5 byte

    // start merging bicycle wheel diameter offset and bicycle weight + putting them in the right order
    byte[] tempWheelDiameterOffset = new byte[1] { bicycleWheelDiameterOffset };
    BitArray bicycleWheelDiameterOffsetBits = new BitArray(tempWheelDiameterOffset);


    byte[] testbicycleWeightBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(bicycleWeight);
    BitArray testBicycleWeight = new BitArray(testbicycleWeightBytes);


    bool[] tempBicycleWeightPartTwo = new bool[8] { testBicycleWeight[4], testBicycleWeight[5], testBicycleWeight[6], testBicycleWeight[7], testBicycleWeight[8], testBicycleWeight[9], testBicycleWeight[10], testBicycleWeight[11] };
    BitArray bicycleWeightBitsTwo = new BitArray(tempBicycleWeightPartTwo);


    bool[] mergeBitsAsBools = new bool[8] { testBicycleWeight[0], testBicycleWeight[1], testBicycleWeight[2], testBicycleWeight[3], bicycleWheelDiameterOffsetBits[0], bicycleWheelDiameterOffsetBits[1], bicycleWheelDiameterOffsetBits[2], bicycleWheelDiameterOffsetBits[3] };
    BitArray tempMergeWheelDiameterOffsetPlusBicycleWeight = new BitArray(mergeBitsAsBools);

    byte[] wheelDiameterOffsetPlusBicycleWeight = new byte[1];
    byte[] bicycleWeightByteTwo = new byte[1];

    tempMergeWheelDiameterOffsetPlusBicycleWeight.CopyTo(wheelDiameterOffsetPlusBicycleWeight, 0);
    bicycleWeightBitsTwo.CopyTo(bicycleWeightByteTwo, 0);
    //end merging


    byte bicycleWheelDiameter = (byte)(0.5 / 0.01); // 0 – 2.54m
    byte gearRatio = (byte)(1 / 0.03); // 0.03 – 7.65
        
        
    bytes[0] = 0xA4;
    bytes[1] = 0x09; // lenght
    bytes[2] = 0x4F; // message type
    bytes[3] = 0x05; // channel
        
    bytes[4] = 0x37; // Page Number 55
    bytes[5] = userWeightBytes[0]; // User Weight LSB
    bytes[6] = userWeightBytes[1]; // User Weight MSB
    bytes[7] = 0xFF; // Reserved for future use
    bytes[8] = wheelDiameterOffsetPlusBicycleWeight[0]; // Bicycle Wheel Diameter Offset 0,5 byte + Bicycle Weight LSN (probably typo in documentation -> LSB?) 0,5 byte
    bytes[9] = bicycleWeightByteTwo[0]; // BicycleWeight MSB
    bytes[10] = bicycleWheelDiameter; // Bicycle Wheel Diameter
    bytes[11] = gearRatio; // Gear Ration
    bytes[12] = ComputeChecksum(bytes); // Method to calcute checksum
        
    return bytes;
}
```

[Ant+ FE-C Data Page 55 (0x3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oyj4.png)
[Ant+ message format structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGijp.jpg)